# How can i prevent users from querying in mvc url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to secure my MVC application by preventing anonymous users from querying application's URL which they get unauthorized info without being logged in so i want to prevent them from doing such thing.. my MVC application has a login authentication page no users can show the data which i provide only through user credential which only admin can provide but if the user   called the correct controller from URL he can show the data without any logging... so i want prevent that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Put [Authorize]  before your controller, for example --

```
[Authorize] 
public class MyController{

}
```

read asp.net mvc security:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security